# Auto-changing of images not working [lightbox2]

Tags: lightbox2

Auto-changing of images is not working in Lightbox2 version 2.9.0.

I have not changed any settings etc., all out of the box. Used on a very old html-page

http://www.provelo-regionthun.ch/index.html

Controls don't show either.

Answer (score 0):

So, try to put this script in a bottom of lightbox.js

```
lightbox.option({
      'wrapAround': true
    });
```

or directly in HTML(before `</body>`)

```
<script>
lightbox.option({
      'wrapAround': true
    })
</script>
```